# Assigning / evaluating concatenated variables in tcsh

Tags: tcsh, csh

I have a tcsh puzzle, and would appreciate any help.

When I run:

```
set faceAttenRuns = (09 13)
set run = $faceAttenRuns[1]
echo $run
```

This returns: *echo 09*.  Great.

But when I run:

```
set runTypes    = (sceneLoc faceAtten faceNorm)
set run = $runTypes[2]Runs[1]
```

This returns: *set: No Match*.  Not great.

How can I make $runTypes[2]Runs[1] return 09, so that 09 can be assigned to the variable *run*?

Thanks!

Comment: IMO the answer to any csh puzzle is "don't use csh for scripting".   seriously, while you may be stuck running existing legacy `csh` scripts, there is **NO** good reason to ever write new `csh` (or `tcsh`) scripts.  Any system that has `csh` will also have at least a basic `sh`, and probably a `ksh` or maybe `bash` or `zsh`.  even a primitive, non-POSIX `sh` is better than `csh` for scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an intermediate variable to perform the operation:

```
set faceAttenRuns = ( 09 13 )
set runTypes = ( sceneLoc faceAtten faceNorm )
set varname = "$runTypes[2]Runs"
echo "set run = "\$"${varname}[1]:q" # this will show you what is going to be evaluated
eval "set run = "\$"${varname}[1]:q"
echo "result=<$run>"
```

---

## Result

```
set run = $faceAttenRuns[1]:q
<09>
```

---

Here's a version without employing any intermediate variables:

```
#!/bin/csh -f

set faceAttenRuns = ( 09 13 )
set runTypes = ( sceneLoc faceAtten faceNorm )

echo "set run = "\$"{${runTypes[2]}Runs[1]:q}"
eval "set run = "\$"{${runTypes[2]}Runs[1]:q}"

echo "result=<$run>"
```